# What's the best way to push realtime data from a serverside c# program to multiple WPF clients?

Tags: c#, tcp, distributed-computing, multicast

I need to develop a system where there'll be around 50 WPF GUI clients running on desktop machines. The main GUI displays a large data grid which gets updated around 500 times a second. It's critical that every GUI grid always displays the same data. To achieve this a single c# serverside program will hold in-memory the primary data grid which will be updated around 500 times a second. I then need to push the updates out the GUIs as fast as possible.

My question is; What's the best way to publish the data? and Is there any open-source libs to do this?

... think multicast over tcp? Are there any c# multicast data replication libs out there which maintain a single master in-memory data table and replicate it out to client programs?

Thanks

Comment: 500 times a second !! what's that!!!

Comment: 500 times a second - Stock prices for a large portfolio.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you eneded up with this but I'm doing something similar and instead of messing with WCF streaming I went with the ZeroMq library.  It can do multicast over tcp via pub-sub and is very fast.  There's a C# interface as well.
http://www.zeromq.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to stream the data, at a refresh rate of 500/second, no normal polling will be able to achieve that especially since you are transferring alot of data. As you said, some form of multicast is needed. WCF supports this in terms of streaming.

Heres a link to get you started with streaming with WCF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx